Safari obscures the fixed bottom bar when scrolling to top on switching to next page
Scroll a little until safari minimizes the address bar, and then click "Next". You can see the bottom bar is obscured. Try scrolling again, the bottom bar restores it's position.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
      const app = document.getElementById('app');
      const state = new Proxy(
        {
          currentPage: 1,
        },
        {
          set(obj, key, value) {
            if (key === 'currentPage') {
              if (value === 1) app.innerHTML = Page1;
              if (value === 2) app.innerHTML = Page2;
              window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }

            obj[key] = value;
            return true;
          },
        }
      );

      const Stepper = `
      <div class="fixed bottom-0 w-full justify-between flex px-10 left-0 right-0 h-20 bg-red-500">
        <button onclick="setCurrentPage(state.currentPage - 1)">
          Back
        </button>
        <button onclick="setCurrentPage(state.currentPage + 1)">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>`;

      const Page1 = `
      <h1 class="text-7xl font-bold">You're currently on page 1</h1>
      <div class="h-[1920px] w-full bg-grey-100"></div>
      ${Stepper}`;

      const Page2 = `
      <h1 class="text-7xl font-bold">You're currently on page 2</h1>
      <div class="h-[1920px] w-full bg-grey-100"></div>
      ${Stepper}
      `;

      const setCurrentPage = (page) =>
        (state.currentPage = Math.min(2, Math.max(1, page)));

      setCurrentPage(state.currentPage);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

See it in action here: https://streamable.com/shm9vd
Try it yourself: https://magnificent-horse-ecfe4e.netlify.app/
Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

It works if you use a smooth scroll instead of an instant scroll.
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

Try the solution yourself.
